# Does MonadTransControl support STM?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I am looking for a standard way to use monad transformers inside STM.atomically.
I think it sounds strange because all use cases I found so far just liftIO . atomically and
pass bare "STM a" without wrapping it into any monad transformer.
I guess, because an atomic action usually is not very complicated - just oneliner and
it is easier and more efficient to pass arguments through local variables,
but in my case transaction is big and I would like to pass the main stack smoothly.

After getting familiar with monad-control library I gravite to opinion
that runInBase cannot unlift monad stack if source and result base
monads are different, but I am not sure.

```
inNestedState :: MyData -> StateT MyState STM ()

loadCounterA :: MyData -> StateT MyState IO ()
loadCounterA md = do
   control $ \runInBase -> atomically (runInBase (inNestedState md))
```

First error

```
monad-control-demo.hs:29:4: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘STM’ with ‘IO’
      Expected type: StateT MyState IO ()
        Actual type: StateT MyState STM ()
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        control $ \ runInBase -> atomically (runInBase (inNestedState md))
      In the expression:
        do control
             $ \ runInBase -> atomically (runInBase (inNestedState md))
      In an equation for ‘loadCounterA’:
          loadCounterA md
            = do control
                   $ \ runInBase -> atomically (runInBase (inNestedState md))
   |
29 |    control $ \runInBase -> atomically (runInBase (inNestedState md))
```

Meanwhile I end up with limited but handy home made solution:

```
class MonadRebase m n where
    rebase :: (m a) -> (n a)

instance (MonadRebase m n) => MonadRebase (ReaderT r m) (ReaderT r n) where
    rebase t = ReaderT $ \r -> rebase (runReaderT t r)

instance (MonadRebase m n) => MonadRebase (StateT s m) (StateT s n) where
    rebase t = StateT $ \s -> rebase (runStateT t s)

instance MonadRebase STM IO where
    rebase = atomically

data MyState = MyState {
      msCounter1 :: TVar Int,
      msCounter2 :: TVar Int,
      ops :: Int
    }

inStm :: ReaderT Int (StateT MyState STM) ()
inStm = do
  rInt <- ask
  lift $ do
          mySt <- get
          modify (\st -> st {ops = rInt + ops st })
          lift $ do
            c1Val <- (readTVar (msCounter1 mySt))
            c2Val <- (readTVar (msCounter2 mySt))
            writeTVar (msCounter1 mySt) 0
            writeTVar (msCounter2 mySt) (c1Val + c2Val)

foo :: ReaderT Int (StateT MyState IO) ()
foo = do
  rebase inStm
```

Any ideas how to do the same with exiting libraries are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question as "How can I convert a `StateT MyState STM ()` to a `StateT MyState IO ()`?". The answer is [`mapStateT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:mapStateT):

```
loadCounterA = mapStateT atomically . inNestedState
```

To go down multiple layers of a transformer stack, as in your second example, simply nest applications of the transformers' respective `map` functions:

```
foo = mapReaderT (mapStateT atomically) inStm
```

When you have a big transformer stack this can be a bit fiddly, but it's the sort of code you can't get wrong thanks to the type checker.